# Как получить экземпляр пользователя в forms.py?

Tags: python, django, forms

Такая проблема, хочу получить в форму записи уже имеющиеся в БД конкретного пользователя и сделать их отображения выбором (`ChoiceField`).

forms.py

```
class TransfersForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(TransfersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

account_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user), label='С какого счёта')
account_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user), label='На какой счёт')
amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Сумма перевода')
```

И во `views.py` при создании формы я пытаюсь передать в форму юзера

views.py

```
def transfers (request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TransfersForm(request.POST, user = request.user)
else:
    form = TransfersForm(user = request.user)
    
return render (request, 'bank/transfers.html', {'menu': menu, 'form': form, 'title': 'Переводы между счетами'})
```

Но так не получается `django` выдает ошибку что в `forms.py`, `self.user` не определён. Если в `forms.py` я прописываю в полях `account_1` и `account_2`

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Bank_Account.objects.all(), label='На какой счёт')
```

то так работает и он возвращает все записи модели `Bank_Account`, но мне нужны только записи юзера который сделал запрос к форме. Подскажите как можно это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом

```
forms.py
class TransfersForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(TransfersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['account_1'].queryset = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user)
    self.fields['account_2'].queryset = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user)

account_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='С какого счёта')
account_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='На какой счёт')
amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Сумма перевода')
```

views.py без изменений.